# Find the side length of a square with line segments of length 1, 2, and 3 extending from each corner and intersecting at their tips

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I know trigonometry should be involved in this somehow but am stuck at where to construct the triangles.

[image]

Comment: Draw the diagonal and use the law of cosines 3 times

Comment: @TheBestMagician Easier approach is to apply the law of cosines to each of the angles in the upper left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Let the origin be at the bottom left corner of the square, and let the point where the line segments meet be $(x,y)$, then

$ x^2 + (y - a)^2 = 1 $

$ (x - a)^2 + (y - a)^2 = 4$

$ x^2 + y^2  = 9 $

These are three quadratic equations in three unknowns with a special structure.  Subtracting (1) from (3), gives us,

$ 2 a y - a^2 = 8 $

Subtracting (2) from (3) gives us

$ 2 a x + 2 a y - 2 a^2 = 5 $

Substracting the last two equations, yields

$ - 2 a x + a^2 = 3 $

Therefore, $ x = \dfrac{ a^2 - 3 }{2 a} $

Plug this into the equation involving $x$ and $y$, and solve for $y$ you get

$ a^2 - 3 + 2 a y - 2 a^2 = 5 $

Therefore,

$ y = \dfrac{ a^2 + 8 }{2 a} $

Now we have expressions for $x$ and $y$ in terms of the side length $a$.  Substitute this into the third equation from the top, you get

$  (a^2 - 3 )^2 + (a^2 + 8)^2 = 36 a^2 $

Let $ u = a^2 $ , then this last equation becomes

$ 2 u^2 - 26 u + 73 = 0$

For which the solutions are

$ u = \dfrac{1}{4} ( 26 \pm \sqrt{92} )  $

From which the two possible side lengths are

$ a_1 \approx 2.02536 $ and $a_2 = 2.9829374 $

Out of which, only the second solution is valid (by checking the values of $x$ and $y$ from the above equations).

Comment: I got that for the second solution (which is $2.9829374$) the point lies inside the square.

Comment: My mistake, I must have been tired.  I re-checked my Math, and you are right.  I must have been confusing $(a)$ and $(a^2).$